# How to temporarily disable protocol tracing during a JavaMail IMAP connection

Tags: debugging, jakarta-mail

You can specify whether JavaMail emits a protocol-level trace either when setting the `Properties` for your `Session` (by setting the `"mail.debug"` property to `"true"`) or by calling [`Session.setDebug`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#setDebug(boolean)) before you do the store connect.

However, when the `Protocol` object gets instantiated, it creates a "protocol" `TraceLogger` that persists for the lifetime of the protocol object.  Which appears to mean that you can't temporarily disable protocol-level debug logging on a connection once you start using it.

There *is* a `Protocol.suspendTracing` method.  And it *does* allow you to temporarily turn off protocol trace output.  A bunch of the IMAP auth methods use it to keep your credentials out of the logfile.  But `suspendTracing` is `protected`, so it's not callable from regular user code.

Is there another way to temporarily turn off IMAP protocol tracing?  (I'd prefer temporarily turning off just the `traceInput` logging, but I'm fine with disabling all logging.)  Do I need to write and register a whole Protocol subclass so I can get access to `Protocol.suspendTracing`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Session.setDebugOut to set your own stream and control it from there.

If you're using java.util.logging, you can change the logging level at any time.

Comment: For the record, could you expand on your answer to indicate the name of the logger to use to switch the log level?

Comment: The logger names are in the [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/).  Scroll to the bottom of the package javadocs for each package.

Comment: These seems like reasonable solutions for an application that has a single JavaMail IMAP connection.  How would one control debug logging for one connection in an application that is maintaining/creating IMAP connections to a large number of servers at once? That is, [without instantiating a separate Session object for each connection](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6278).

Comment: How would I do it without using the letter 'e' in my code?  If you keep adding enough requirements, the answer will be that it's impossible!  :-)  If you've proven that the performance of using a separate Session per connection is unacceptable in your application, I don't have a simple answer for you.  You could create your own SocketFactory and do your own socket level logging.  You'll miss all the JavaMail debug output, but maybe that's good enough for your needs.  Or write your own LogManager that uses Loggers that are multiplexed per connection.

Comment: I suppose that I'm pointing out that your solution is more of a workaround and was hoping that there was a different, API-level way to turn off logging for a single connection. But that should be addressed in a JavaMail enhancement request, and I'll go and file one. (Though if per-connection `Session` objects aren't as expensive as [bug 6278](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6278) makes them out to be, that's a real solution.)

Comment: Try the per-connection Session objects and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but, you can install a custom log filter on the com.sun.mail.imap.protocol logger to check that some specific thread is allowed to produce output.  Assuming your connection is local to one thread

```
    public class ServiceFilter implements Filter {

        private static final ThreadLocal<javax.mail.Service> id = new ThreadLocal<>();

        public static void suspendTracing(javax.mail.Service s) {
            id.set(Objects.requireNonNull(s));
        }

        public static void enableTracing(javax.mail.Service s) {
            if (s.equals(id.get())) {
                id.remove();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
            return id.get() == null;
        }
    }
```

The downside is that this code becomes part of your project and it is another resource that you have to manage.